# Why is "وليتلطف" in Surah Kahaf is written in bold text in Quran?

Tags: quran, arabic-translation

I have seen the word **وليتلطف** in ***Surah Kahaf*** in the Quran written in bold text.

I want to know:

1. The reason why this word is in bold?
2. What is the meaning of this word according to Tafseer or Ahaadith?

Comment: Be aware that this isn't the case in most moshaf copies (for example neither the copies printed Saudi Arabia nor those spread in northern Africa, show this word in bold letters). So your observation can hardly be retraced by others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scholar Mohamed Altahir Bin Ashoor, in his tafseer for the Quran `التحرير والتنوير` consider it to be the word of half of the Quran.

`وليتلطف`

Same person also - by logical inheritance, that the `Ta` `ت` in it, is the letter middle of the Quran (since it is the middle of that word).

However, that opinion is not shared by all, as in Tafseer Ibn Atia `ابن عطية` claims that Alnawawi claims that the middle of the Quran is the word:

`نكرا`

in the same Surah Ayah 74.

This could also be effected by many scholars who consider the `بسم الله الرحمان الرحيم` to be an Ayah for the Fatiha while many others don't, that calculations into consideration.

Fatwa Source: https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/65007

Answer (score 1):

It is considered to be the **middle most word of the Quran**.

Answer (score 0):

Walyatalatf is the pillars of the Qur'an, it is balanced and balancer and as humanity is condensed to ADAM so the whole Qur'an is condensed to this word walyatalatf.it is adrop at the same time it is an ocean. From that ocean we can fetch what ever amount according to our capacities but the ocean remains the same as if untouched

Answer (score -1):

It is reported to be the central word of the Holy Quran

Comment: It is reported to have link with Ayat 143 of Sura Al baqra(Sura2:143)

Answer (score -1):

Allah gives us everything in these universe for our services except two things he want it back.one service second trust. Service and trust both included in walyatataf